# pd.merge for multiple dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I just realized, that

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

does not seem to work for multiple, i.e. 5 DataFrames?

All the 5 data frames have the same index called "time".
Also, all have the same column named "temperature".

Can this be done?

Hint: I experimented with *join.* but wasn't happy with the result.

Answer (score 3):

[pd.concat()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) method can concatenate a list of DataFrames:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5], axis=1)
```